# How is '<' handled in Unix?

Tags: c, shell, unix, io-redirection

I was testing `argv[]` in C and noticed that if you type in the shell something like

```
./program.out <
```

the '`<`' is not read as an argument but as something else and it gives me an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Can someone explain what that is?

Comment: Your shell is a complex thing. Read its documentation to learn how it works.

Comment: Are you asking about zshell, c-shell or korn shell?

Comment: Google: bash redirection

Comment: @siguza: i suppose you meant "redirection" instead of `|`.

Comment: @rici yep, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` and `>` are two of the many *redirection* operators in Bash (and most other shells). They act by redirecting stdin and stdout to/from a source respectively. When you write `a.out <`, your shell is expecting a file name after the `<`, being the location to read standard input from. Without specifying anything, your shell encounters the trailing new line and errors out.

If you want to pass a literal '<' to your program you'll need to *escape* it - either `a.out '<'`, or `a.out \<`.

Further reading: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: I was asked in a programming assignment to code a cat program by using system calls and for that I think I need to buffer the redirection operators to correctly parse the command. How would you go about this. I have to parse $ ./mycat < file1 > file2.

Comment: @daniel: are you writing a shell or just a program that a shell will run?  If you're writing a program, you ignore redirection; the shell takes care of it.  Your code reads standard input and writes to standard output.  If file names are given as arguments, open, read, close each file in turn. If you're writing a shell, then say so.  The issues you face are completely different.

Comment: Just writing a program.